# Dynamic properties in Symfony Entity Class

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony3.x

I want to load a variable dynamically with values from an unmapped database (separate Entity Manager "ps"). I created the variable $categories for example.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;


/**
 * ModProduct
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mod_product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ModProduct
{
...
public static $categories = [];
...
}
```

Now I want to fill this property with values. I thought of the following solutions:

- Create a Repository file, but this can only create "findBy"-functions, afaik
- Load the Entity Manager in the Entity Class, but this is considers bad practice and I can't really find a way to do so.
- Indirect way: load the data from the PS-Database into a e.g. json file and create a __construct in the Entity to populate the $categories variable

The result should simply be, whenever I need ModProduct::$categories it should have fetched the categories once from the secondary database and populated the array for further usage.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably create a [postLoad](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postload) event-listener and use it to do whatever you need when the entity is loaded.

Therefore just create a new class

```
// Event listener

namespace Whatever;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class MyEventListener
{
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        // your logic here..
    }
}
```

then declare it as a service with related tag

```
  // services.yaml

  Whatever\MyEventListener:
      tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad, method: postLoad }
```

More info in the [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html).